# How to update the scrollWheelZoom in react-leaflet v3?

Tags: react-leaflet

I want to upgrade from `react-leafet` v2 to v3 and can't figure out how to update the `scrollWheelZoom` after initilization so I can control when the map can be zoomed by mouse wheel and when not. In v2, I could simply pass a react state variable to the `scrollWheelZoom` prop and update the state accordingly. Since this doesn't seem to be working anymore with v3, I tried to change the option directly on the map instance from the initial value false to true:

```js
const map = useMap();
const someEventHandler = () => {
  map.options.scrollWheelZoom = true;
};
```

I can see that the value of `map.options.scrollWheelZoom` actually changed but the map is still not scrollable. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I had a look into [how this is done in `react-leaflet`'s source code of v2](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/d9f18e527495105bab1df65a8829422514daefd7/src/Map.js#L236).

So I ended up with the following which works well for me:

```js
const setScrollWheelZoom(scrollWheelZoom: boolean) => {
  if (scrollWheelZoom !== map.options.scrollWheelZoom) {
    map.options.scrollWheelZoom = scrollWheelZoom;
    if (scrollWheelZoom) {
      map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
    } else {
      map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
    }
  }
}
```

As a side note: I am not sure though, why, in the react-leaflet source code, `options.scrollWheelZoom` is only set when enabling. For me, this makes the first condition fail when trying to enable it a second time.